Product of scalar plus cell-range in Numbers.app
Is there any way in Numbers.app to take the product of 1+cell-range, e.g. PRODUCT[1+B1:B10], without creating a temporary column of 1+B? This seems possible in Excel, according to Using Indirect formula in Excel to get the product of 1 + Cell Range. But the trick of using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER does not seem to work in Numbers.app.
